# Carrierwave leaves RackMultipart files in Rails root (development env)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

So, whenever I upload a file in dev mode in Rails with Carrierwave, I get these temporary `RackMultipart*` files right in the Rails root. Even though in `config/carrierwave.rb` I have the following setting:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.cache_dir = 'tmp/uploads'
end
```

And no, I didn't change cache dir in the uploader. Worst of all, it seems like for every new file upload, it creates 2 identical (in content, but not in name) `RackMultipart*` files. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: AFAIK RackMultipart has nothing to do with carrierwave it somnething what Rack.

Comment: I'm running the same issue, did you found a way to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with the sticky bit.

You must do :

```
chmod o+t /tmp
```

Then in rails console check the path with :

```
Dir::tmpdir
```

Comment: When a directory's sticky bit is set, the filesystem treats the files in such directories in a special way so only the file's owner, the directory's owner, or root user can rename or delete the file. [Sticky Bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit)